# Split off repo subdirectory into its own repo, auto-update new repo from larger repo

Tags: git, repository, gitlab

Due to limitations of a bug scanning software we use, we cannot scan a sub-directory of our GIT repo that we need to. Repo A has just been exported from SVN and splitting it into permanent separate repos is not possible yet.

What we want to do is take subfolder B of repo A and spin it off into its own repo (repo B) that can be accessed by the scanner. Repo B would ideally be auto-updated when Repo A is. Or, repo B could be manually synced from repo A when we need to run a bug scan.

I have checked out repo A and used filter-branch to whittle it down to just subdirectory B, in hopes of creating a new small repo B. But tying repo B to repo A for auto-updating seems.. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use [git subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17864475/7976758)

Comment: Would a [githook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) do what you want with [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)?